# Erro de conexão MySql Xampp

Tags: mysql

O Xaamp apresenta o seguinte erro e não conecta com o MySql

```
13:39:38  [mysql]   Problem detected!
13:39:38  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
13:39:38  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:39:38  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:39:38  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Comment: Seja Bem Vindo Jean, esse erro significa que a porta 3306 já está sendo utilizada, configure através do painel do xampp uma outra porta para o mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente, esse erro ocorre por causa de um processo chamado "mysqlid" que é executado na porta 3306. Recomendaria você localizar esse processo dessa maneira: 
Abra o cmd, digite `netstat -o -n -a` e procure pela porta 3306 (o endereço com uma sequência de 0's e a porta) em "Local Address" (ou "Endereço Local"). Ao localizá-la, observe o PID em questão. Feito isso vá ao seu gerenciador de tarefas, na aba de serviços e finalize o processo de acordo com o PID observado no passo anterior(provavelmente será o "mysqlid"). Agora basta reiniciar o serviço pelo XAMPP.